# 404 not found for Encrypted values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wcf, encryption, service

I am trying to send encrypted values to my WCF service, but I get a 404 Error when sending the encrypted data but not the normal values?

My normal values that sends successfully are pulled straight from my html:

> app@mail.com

and this is my encryption value:

```
var encryptedemail = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(Email), key,  
            {  
                keySize: 128 / 8,  
                iv: iv,  
                mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,  
                padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7  
            });
```

service Link:

```
 $http.get("http://localhost:8100/Service.svc/Method/" + encryptedemail)
          .success(function(data) {});
          .error(function(data) {});
```

I noticed that the **encryptedemail** value was in an object format so I tried to convert it to string but it made no difference.

```
var a = String(encryptedemail);
```

but still the same issue, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$scope.data = {encryptedemail : encryptedemail};
$http.get("http://localhost:8100/Service.svc/Method",$scope.data)
      .success(function(data) {});
      .error(function(data) {});
```

Comment: yeah that did it, could you maybe explain why this worked?

Comment: you were sending encrypted string through url, it was making URL-unsafe. strings can contain the "+", "=" and "/" characters which could alter the meaning of your data